# IPython won't stop compiling to .pyc while debugging IPython source code

Tags: python, debugging, ipython

I'm trying to make my first contribution to IPython. Currently, in the process of trying to debug a file. When I run the ipython interpreter:

```
~/opensource/ipython$ ipython
```

The interpreter will not acknowledge the changes I made to my local copy of this file:

```
~/opensource/ipython/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py
```

Instead, it runs a compiled copy (.pyc) of what I think is the original. Do you know how I can can the interpreter to import changes I've made to interactiveshell.py .

Sorry if this is a newbie question, trying to make my first pull request. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can always safely delete .pyc files if you think they're causing a problem, but Python normally checks the time that they were modified, so they shouldn't interfere. You may need to install IPython again after changing it, though - run `python setup.py install`.

Comment: If you installed it using ``setup.py install`` you will absolutely have to reinstall it every time you make a change. ``ipython`` in ``usr/local/bin`` doesn't point to your original source copy, it made a new copy in ``usr/local/lib/pythonX.X/dist-packages`` and loads that. Even if you launched the IPython script it directly from the source folder rather than using the ``ipython`` command, the copy in ``dist-packages`` will be earlier in the python-path, so it will load first.

Comment: After running  python setup.py  install and deleting the .pyc file, the changes still haven't showed up. I'm running my copy of ipython in virtualenv, is there something I should be removing in there as well?

Comment: Also tried installing ipython using the -e flag. When I was in the  ~/opensource/ipython folder, I ran "pip install -e ."

Comment: Was able to find a solution by creating a new virtualenv, then following your suggestions to reinstall Ipython. Thank you for your help